# Normalisation from 2nf to bcnf

Tags: normalization

This is a question from a textbook

```
Consider the Relation R={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H } and the set of functional dependencies.
A→C B→CG AD→EH C→DF A→H
What is the key for R? Decompose R into 2NF, 3NF and finally in BCNF relation
```

I believe `A B` are the candidate key.

I have decomposed R to 2nf like this:

```
R1={A,C,H,D,F,E,H}
R2={B,C,G,D,G,F}
R3={A,B}
```

For 3nf:

```
R1A={A,C,H}
R1B={C,D,F}
R2={B,C,G}
R3={A,B}
R4={A,D,E}
```

**My Problem**

This clearly doesn't look right as we still have multiple anomalies and no relation to convert to bcnf. How am I supposed to correctly normalize R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize in 3NF one should start from a canonical cover of the functional dependences. In this case one is:

```
{ A → C
A → E
A → H
B → C
B → G
C → D
C → F }
```

So a decomposition in 3NF with the “synthesis” algorithm is:

```
R1 < (A C E H) ,
{ A → C E H } >

R2 < (B C G) ,
{ B → C G } >

R3 < (C D F) ,
{ C → D F } >

R4 < (A B) ,
{ } >
```

Starting from R, a possible decomposition in BCNF with the “analysis” algorithm is:

```
R1 < (B G) ,
{ B → G } >

R2 < (A B) ,
{ } >

R3 < (C D F) ,
{ C → D
C → F } >

R4 < (A C E H) ,
{ A → C
A → E
A → H } >
```

Note that with this decomposition the dependency `B → C` is lost.